# how to show an image in gmail inbox preview

Tags: email, gmail, gmail-promo-tab

I have been receiving promotional emails with an image along with the subject line. i have seen this only in Gmail. 
Not emojis, but image preview right below the subject line portion in the inbox preview
The emails are much more catchy with this. I have been checking google for a while to see what this feature is called but could not find any clue on the same. 
Any information on this is Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

[Gmail Promotion Annotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/toxtn.png)
Since 2018 you can, indeed, add images with a preview in Gmail by using JSON-LD markup in the email's head.
Gmail Promotions Tabs can have/show:

- Logo
- Image
- Subject
- Deal Badges with Dates Frames
- Discount Code within a Badge Design

The customization is quite strict, as of now, but the google guidelines are commented in the code snippet below:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
 [{
   "@context": "http://schema.org/",
   "@type": "Organization",

   // WARNING: Before sending email, either point the logo
   // at your own image or delete the logo annotation.
   //
   // If showing a logo, we recommend using an https URL.
   // It's not a requirement today, but may be in the future.
   "logo": "https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/product/1x/googleg_48dp.png"
  },{
   "@context": "http://schema.org/",
   "@type": "EmailMessage",

   // Use this optional alternative subject line to avoid duplicate text
   // between the subject, deal badge, and discount code.
   "subjectLine": "[Important] Please add subject line in annotation"
  },{
   "@context": "http://schema.org/",
   "@type": "DiscountOffer",

   // Describe your discount, this will be shown as a badge (eg "25% off" or "free 
      shipping")
   "description": "20% off",

   "discountCode": "PROMO",
   "availabilityStarts": "2019-07-21T03:42:38-07:00",
   "availabilityEnds": "2019-07-24T03:42:38-07:00"
  },{
   // Promotion card with single image.
   // We recommend using an https URL.  It's not a requirement today, but may be in 
       the future.
   // Any image size will work and will just be cropped automatically.
   // GIF & WEBP images are not supported and will be filtered out.
   // Sample image is 538x138, 3.9 aspect ratio
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@type": "PromotionCard",
    "image": "https://www.google.com/gmail-for-marketers/promo-tab/markup- 
     tool/sample.png"
 }]
</script>
```

Resources for this answer can be found in Google Developers Documentation:
[Promotion Tab Documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/promotab/overview)

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nszbe.jpg)

This is the image of gmail inbox preview for product listing.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Add a Event onmouseover=FuntionName() to each GridView row, and show the popup which will include the message. But get it from client side

Comment: Thank you.I am sorry i do not have a screenshot to explain this. but functions would not work in gmail inbox as far as i know. further more, the preview images in the kind of emails i am talking about goes away after a day's time. it's a very interesting trick what so ever.